# Robolectric slow when using constants or manifest in @Config

Tags: android, junit, android-resources, robolectric

If I annotate my test class with the following, all of my test cases run very fast.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)    
@Config(packageName = "com.my.app")
```

Unfortunately, any of my test cases that access string resources, fail because the resources can not be found:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f090172
```

If I annotate my class with:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", packageName = "com.my.app")
```

OR

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, packageName = "com.my.app")
```

...performance is terrible (8ms vs 30-40sec) per test case

It seems that whenever I use the `constants` or `manifest` configurations, it slows down my test significantly for each and every test. As a result, when my builds are running on a build server, they are often failing because the build times out.

Is there any way to get the performance I was having before (or close to it) while still being able to access resources (strings)?

Comment: And why do you need to define such constants?

Comment: If I don't put the constants, I can't access the local android string resources

Comment: You can `@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 25)`

Comment: Yes, but when I do this, it slows my tests down by a LOT. That is the issue.